# jQuery tooltip flickers on links when position is specified

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

When I add a tooltip to a normal link, and specify the position (any position), the tooltip will only show if the mouse is hovered exactly over the text. If I don't specify a position, it works all hunky dory.

This is incredibly disheartening, considering this is basic functionality.

I've replicated this in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6EZHZ/65/

It's also worth mentioning that the given example in documentation works:

```
$( ".selector" ).tooltip({ 
    position: { my: "left+15 center", at: "right center" } 
});
```

Why is this happening? Is there a good solution that's not an ugly hack?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
.tip {
    background-color: white;
    display:block;
}
```

By default, when you hover over the letters - and by letters, I mean the actual letters, not the in-between space - only then is the effect started.
When you set the display to be block property it treats it as a rectangle covering the inner letters.
So that even if you hover over the inner in-between spaces it activates the 'block'.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. While this is definitely what's happening, it seems that jquery-ui overcomes this when not specifying a position. What I'm wondering is why it's not there when specifying a position, and what to do about it.

Specifying block also breaks the flow of the text. I tried inline-block but it flickers too.